# Appendix with alphabetical label

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

I would like to have my appendices labelled 'Appendix A', 'Appendix B', etc. as below.

I'm using `\documentclass{book}`.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us how you're creating the appendices at the moment.

Comment: Apart from the centering the instruction `\usepackage[title]{appendix}` should be sufficient for this, I would redefine `\@makechapterhead` however for this to prevent mess-up of the ToC.

Comment: Please add a compilable document -- the screenshot is not really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do what you need.

If this doesn't fit your needs, please edit your question and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\Huge}
{\Huge\bfseries\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
{20pt}
{}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Short chapter title}
    \section{Section title}
    \begin{theorem}
        \LaTeX\ is fun!
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        Ducks are fun!
    \end{theorem}

    \section{Section title}
    \begin{theorem}
        \LaTeX\ is fun!
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        Ducks are fun!
    \end{theorem}

    \chapter[Long chapter title]{Long long long long long long chapter title}
    \section{Section title}
    \begin{theorem}
        \LaTeX\ is fun!
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        Ducks are fun!
    \end{theorem}
    \section{Section title}
    \begin{theorem}
        \LaTeX\ is fun!
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        Ducks are fun!
    \end{theorem} 

    \appendix

    \chapter{Short appendix title}
    \section{Section title}
    \begin{theorem}
        This is a simple way to do what you need.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        Since you didn't provide a MWE, I cannot know if this is actually what you need!
    \end{theorem}
    \section{Section title}
    \begin{theorem}
        Why don't people provide a MWE?
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        A MWE is always needed!
    \end{theorem}

    \chapter[Long appendix title]{Long long long long long long appendix title}
    \section{Section title}
    \begin{theorem}
        \LaTeX\ is fun!
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        Ducks are fun!
    \end{theorem}
    \section{Section title}
    \begin{theorem}
        \LaTeX\ is fun!
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{theorem}
        Ducks are fun!
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version without any other package apart from `appendix` package by 'slightly' (cough! ;-)) modifying the `\@makechapterhead` command.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}


\newlength{\appendixafterchapheadskip}
\newlength{\appendixbeforechapheadskip}
\newlength{\appendixafterchaptitleskip}
\setlength{\appendixafterchapheadskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\appendixbeforechapheadskip}{30pt}
\setlength{\appendixafterchaptitleskip}{30pt}


\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendices{%
  \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{\appendixbeforechapheadskip}%
    { \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
      \huge\bfseries\centering \@chapapp\space \thechapter
      \par\nobreak
      \vskip \appendixafterchapheadskip
      \fi
      \fi
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
      \vskip \appendixafterchaptitleskip%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Regular chapter}


\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Foo appendix}
\section{Some foo appendix section}
\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

[image]